# convert linear acceleration into world frames in android

Tags: android, orientation, accelerometer, motion

I have orientation sensor giving me the orientation angles (or quaternion) in the world's coordinate. Now I get the Linear acceleration from TYPE_LINEAR_ACCELERATION, which gives the acceleration in phone's coordinates. Now the question is how I convert the acceleration from phone's coordinates to world coordinates?
thanks

Comment: Can you share some of your current code or what you have already tried to solve this so we can better help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need Rotation matrix not orientation values

If you have orintation angles you can convert them a rotation matrix

[Rotation Matrix from Euler Angles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5v8cq.png)

After you get the rotation matrix if you multiply it with the acceleration in the earth coordinate system you will get the acceleration in the phone coordinate system

a_p = acceleration in the phone coordinate system

R = Rotation Matrix

a_e = acceleration in the earth coordinate system

a_p = R * a_e

and inverse of the rotation matrix is equal to its transpose

R^-1 = R^T

a_e = R^T * a_p

it means if you multiply the transpose of rotation matrix with phones reading you will get acceleration in the earth coordinate system